# Is there a geometric meaning to the outer product of two vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces

Define two vectors ***v*** and ***u*** in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I know the geometric meaning of the inner and cross product.

Is there a meaning to the matrix resulting from $\textbf{uv}^T$?

Comment: What do you know about tensors and their role in geometric constructs?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For any vector $x$,
$$
uv^T(x) = (v \cdot x)u
$$
That is, If $u$ and $v$ are unit vectors, $uv^T(x)$ is the component of $x$ in the $v$ direction, taken into the $u$ direction.

This interpretation makes for a neat understanding of [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition).

Comment: I think you mean "...component of $x$ in the $v$ direction, taken into the $u$ direction".

Comment: @niran90 that's right good catch