# Geometric meaning of outer product of a vector with itself

Tags: linear-algebra

This question is related to the question in the link below:

[Is there a geometric meaning to the outer product of two vectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965633/is-there-a-geometric-meaning-to-the-outer-product-of-two-vectors)

The answer is clear, but I am wondering: If we take a outer product of a vector with itself, then is there a specific geometric meaning of the matrix which is not evident from an interpretation of the outer product of two general vectors?

Comment: Do you mean outer product of _two_ vectors (in three dimensional Euclidean space) in your title? I cannot see what an outer product of one vector would be. The outer product of any vector with itself is the zero vector.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I think OP means the outer product of a vector with itself.

Comment: @Travis excellent, would mind to have a look at my other question and .. any comment would be highy appreciated. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1247598/understanding-eigenvector

Comment: It appears I misinterpreted [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) as cross product, or vector product. Deleting my answer

Comment: @Creator I edited the title and body of the question for clarity; would you please ensure that I've managed to preserved your intended meaning and revert/modify as necessary?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $\bf x$ is a unit vector, then the linear transformation
$${\bf y} \mapsto ({\bf x}{\bf x}^T)({\bf y}) = ({\bf x} \cdot {\bf y}) \bf x$$ defined by the outer product ${\bf x}{\bf x}^T$ is the orthogonal projection of $\bf y$ onto the line spanned by $\bf x$. For general $\bf x$, the linear transformation is this projection composed with dilation by a factor ${\bf x} \cdot {\bf x} = ||{\bf x}||^2$.

Comment: I think that the answer is simply "it's an area element" from the geometrical standpoint is the ellipsoid build on the matrix x x^T

Comment: @Fabio how does this generalize to projecting $y$ onto the subspace spanned by the columns of a matrix? I posted a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4179772/project-a-vector-onto-subspace-spanned-by-columns-of-a-matrix)